# Mail configuration information could not be read from the database

Tags: sql-server-2005, service-pack, email

Recently I've updated SQL Server 2005 with SP4. After updating DB mails are not working from Jobs and from T-SQL as well.

Following exception is thrown.

```
1) Exception Information  ===================  Exception Type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.Server.Common.BaseException
```

Message: Mail configuration information could not be read from the database.

Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal  TargetSite: Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.Server.Objects.Account GetAccount(Int32)  HelpLink: NULL  Source: DatabaseMailEngine    StackTrace Information  ===================     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.Server.DataAccess.DataAccessAdapter.GetAccount(Int32 accountID)     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.Server.Controller.CommandFactory.CreateSendMailCommand(DBSession dbSession)     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.Server.Controller.CommandRunner.Run(DBSession db)     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.IMailProcess.ThreadCallBack.MailOperation(Object o)    2) Exception Information  ===================  Exception Type: System.IndexOutOfRangeException  Message: timeout  Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal  TargetSite: Int32 GetOrdinal(System.String)  HelpLink: NULL  Source: System.Data    StackTrace Information  ===================     at System.Data.ProviderBase.FieldNameLookup.GetOrdinal(String fieldName)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetOrdinal(String name)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_Item(String name)     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.Server.DataAccess.DataAccessAdapter.GetAccount(Int32 accountID)

As per MSDN, it has to do when ProductVersion and ResourceVersion are different. however as checked both of them are same.

OS - Windows Server 2008 64 bit.
SQL Server - SQL Server 2005 64 bit, recently updated to SP4.
DB mails are eanbled.

Any possible solution or workarounds would be apperciated.

Answer (score 1):

[This KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2008286) seems to imply that it is a bug in SQL Server 2008 SP1 & 2005 SP3. It has not been updated to include SP4. Did you go directly from SP3 -> SP4 in a relatively short time? The condition may have occurred when you installed SP3 but you weren't at SP3 long enough to notice. Or you may have been at SP3 + some CU that included the fix, but SP4 undid the fix. Seems quite strange to me that they would cause this problem in two different service packs, and not learn enough from it that they repeated it again on a subsequent service pack.

I would suggest either (a) uninstalling the service pack to restore functionality temporarily, or (b) applying [Cumulative Update #3 for SP4](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2507769) to see if the fix made it into one of the updates since SP4 was released (I don't see it listed explicitly on any of their individual KB articles, but they aren't always listed individually).